# Why empty space in CSS table-cells?

Tags: css

Why does the cells left and right get filled with empty space?

The empty space is above the left and right table-cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tim86/NU9sA/

It has something to do with the `#middlebuttons{display:block;}`.

EDIT: I am using Firefox 5.

EDIT2: Pictues

Wrong

[image: wrong]

Right

[image: ![right]

Comment: Tim, are you talking about empty spaces in the list boxes named 'Alla studenter' and 'Grupp 1'?

Comment: Which elements are you asking about?

Comment: I put <br /> after each button instead of using `#middlebuttons{display:block;}` to solve my problem.
[Here is the updated code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tim86/NU9sA/1/)

But does anyone have an explanation on this behavior, please tell me.

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh 
No, I mean the empty space above the "Alla studenter" and "Grupp 1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=634489) in Firefox. The workaround seems to be to add the following:

```
#middleButtons {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Was looking at this for a while in Chrome and couldn't see the problem!

Comment: Thank you very much! You must be a real CSS pro!

Comment: Happy to help. Also I forgot to say that I like your approach for adding the students to different groups.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I am actually quite proud about it. Glad you mentioned it ^^. Later I am adding some functionality for dividing them automatically after some variables.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use float: left instead of table-cell?
http://jsfiddle.net/NU9sA/5/

Comment: I am afraid that floating elements gets me in trouble when using auto to size child-elements. I don't use it know but may use auto sizing later.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `float: left;` in

```
#middleButtons input
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `padding` off the top of the `div` for `#ungroupedStudentsWrapper`.

So do this

```
#middleButtons, #ungroupedStudentsWrapper, #groupWrapper 
{ 
    display: table-cell; 
    padding:0 .8em .8em .8em; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/NU9sA/7/

Comment: The padding does not affect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set a height of 300px on the first select element.

```
<div>Alla studenter</div>
<select style="height:300px;" id="UngroupedStudents" multiple="multiple" name="UngroupedStudents" size="4">
```

The white space shows as this select element contains 7 option elements which are less than the specified height of 300px

```
<option value="Anatoly">Anatoly</option>
<option value="Marie">Marie</option>
<option value="Sara">Sara</option>
<option value="Peter">Peter</option>
<option value="Jocke">Jocke</option>
<option value="Sinan">Sinan</option>
<option value="Tom">Tom</option>
```

If you remove the height or make the height less than the space required to display the above 7 option elements, the white psace will be removed.

For the second select element inside the

```
  <div class="groupHeader" id="gh1">Grupp 1</div>
```

You have set styles as

```
 select 
 { 
 min-width:100px; 
 min-height: 100px;
 }
```

As this select element only contains 4 options elements

```
<option value="Tim">Tim</option>
<option value="Jens">Jens</option>
<option value="Ann">Ann</option>
<option value="Anders">Anders</option>
```

The specified height of 100px is more than the space required to display the above 4 option element, so the white space.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnUvU/)

Comment: Thanks you, but its not the white space i was targeting. I was to unclear with my question from the beginning, sorry for that.